# Syntax Error in PostgreSql JSONField in django models

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model

```
from django.db import models                    
from django.contrib.postgres.fields   
import JSONField
class Fixture_lineups(models.Model):                
        fixture_id = 
        models.ForeignKey("Fixture",
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        home_formation =   
        models.CharField()
        home_start_xi = JSONField()                         
        home_substitutes = JSONField()                  
        away_formation =
        models.CharField()                                                   
        away_start_xi = JSONField()                        
        away_substitutes = JSONField()
        lastUpdate =    
        models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

After creating this model i was trying to do migrations to my database(PostgreSql) but my traceback said me that in my model is syntax error.

```
away_start_xi = JSONField()                        
away_substitutes = JSONField()
```

But i can not find this syntax error. Here is traceback

```
  $ python manage.py makemigrations         
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>            main()                                          
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main                execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)             
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line                            utility.execute()                            
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute                                              django.setup()
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate        app_config.import_models()                       
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)                                        
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/env/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module                   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import                                 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load                                 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked                      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked                               
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 860, in get_code                           
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 791, in source_to_code                     
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed                    File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/predictions/forecast/dataflow/models.py", line 81
away_start_xi = JSONField()                       
away_substitutes = JSONField()
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Do you have old migrations that might have an error? And please include the stracktrace / error message.

Comment: No, i haven't any migrations. It is first. I added Traceback

Comment: You have plenty of syntax errors here. You can't arbitrarily split lines like that.

Comment: I didn't split those lines. They split automaticaly because i publish my question from stackoverflow mobile app

Comment: Please reformat your code so it's exactly the way you have it on your local machine. Otherwise it's impossible for us to tell if there is a syntax error. Note that the traceback you posted doesn't mention a syntax error, there's probably something missing here, so also please re-paste the correct traceback when you're not on mobile.